# Error: mysqladmin: refresh failed; error: 'Unknown error'

Tags: mysql

My problem started when I was tired to get emails every day from Cron Daemon. The emails look like this:

```
From: Cron Daemon <root@xxx.xxx>
Date: 2014-08-25 6:29 GMT+03:00
Subject: Cron <root@xxx> test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
To: root@xxx.xxx


/etc/cron.daily/logrotate:
/usr/bin/mysqladmin: refresh failed; error: 'Unknown error'
error: error running shared postrotate script for '/var/log/mysql.log /var/log/mysql/mysql.log /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log /var/log/mysql/error.log '
run-parts: /etc/cron.daily/logrotate exited with return code 1
```

I have 40 emails like this in my inbox. A method that I found it's said that the problem comes from the fact that password debian.cnf not corspunde with another password. So I tride this in mysql console:

```
GRANT RELOAD, SHUTDOWN, PROCESS, SHOW DATABASES, SUPER, LOCK TABLES ON *.* TO 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'XXXXXXXX’;flush-privileges;
```

After this I did this check:

```
 $ mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf ping
```

result:

```
mysqld is alive
```

Ok, but the emails stil not stoped. So when I run:

```
$ mysqladmin -u root -p flush-log
```

result:

```
mysqladmin: refresh failed; error: 'Unknown error'
```

So, how can I debug this, any ideas?

*UPDATE:* This is a bug, from what I read. I suggest to let it go and make an update to mysql-server and mysql-client. Cheers!

```
$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.6 mysql-client-5.6
```

Answer (score 15):

I had the same error. The solution was to fix permissions of log directory & files:

```
sudo chown -Rv mysql /var/log/mysql
```

The update/reinstall helped you probably because the mysql install script fixed the permissions for you.

Comment: it will also happen if you have custom directive in your my.cnf (in my case different path to log-error)