# MySQL - Unable to load slow_log table

Tags: mysql

We've had slow-log enabled for years:

slow-query-log=1

log-output=TABLE

Never had any problems retrieving the records from the table to review the results. About a week ago, I tried to retrieve the results with a SELECT statement. That attempt timed out. So, I tried to just "open the table" using HeidiSQL and SQLyog. HeidiSQL never completes the load (locks up the IDE), SQLyog fails with a MySQL error:

Executed SQL statement: select * from `mysql`.`slow_log` limit 0, 1000
Error number: 2000
Error message: Unknown MySQL error

I've tried under my own user account and as root, from both my own machine and on the server directly (localhost).

I tried TRUNCATING the table. That commands succeeds, but takes a very long time. I thought the table was maybe filling with too many records, but SQLyog indicates there are only 30 records right now.

What could be causing this and how do I fix it? We've made no server changes (MySQL versions or my.ini changes).

This MySQL server is a replicated master. I enabled slow-log on the slave, as the slave is used for some read-only tasks. I can access the slow-log table just fine on the slave. Don't know that that means anything, but in case it's helpful.

FYI, we run MySQL Server on Windows machines (Server 2012 R2).

Answer (score 0):

I did some googling, and it's practically un-findable, but I did found this:

> I had the same error. The solution was to fix permissions of log
>   directory & files:
>
> sudo chown -Rv mysql /var/log/mysql The update/reinstall helped you
>   probably because the mysql install script fixed the permissions for
>   you.

[Quote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26971131/1103589)

Comment: That solution is for logging to **file**, but we are logging to **table**.